# Openpyxl 1.8.5: Reading the result of a formula typed in a cell using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am printing some formula in one of the Excel sheets:

```
wsOld.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = "=B3=B4"
```

But I cannot use its result in implementing some other logic, as:

```
if((wsOld.cell(row=1, column=1).value)='true'):
    # copy the 1st row to another sheet
```

Even when I am trying to print the result in the command line, I end up printing the formula:

```
>>> print(wsOld.cell(row=1, column=1))
>>> =B3=B4
```

How can I get the result of the formula in a cell and not the formula itself?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

openpyxl support either the formula or the value of the formula. You can select which using the `data_only` flag when opening a workbook. However, openpyxl does not and will not calculate the result of a formula. There are libraries out there like pycel which purport to do this.

Comment: FWIW, as documented in `openpyxl.load_workbook()`, the value that you get when opening a Workbook with `data_only=True` is "the value stored the last time Excel read the sheet". This relies on a caching feature of .xls[x/m/...] files (about which I find documentation everywhere except at Microsoft).

Answer (score 10):

[xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/), [PyXll](https://www.pyxll.com/) [FlyingKoala](https://github.com/bradbase/flyingkoala), DataNitro all use Excel as the interface to using Python.

If you want to use a Python library you can try [PyCel](https://github.com/stephenrauch/pycel), [xlcalculator](https://github.com/bradbase/xlcalculator), [Formulas](https://github.com/vinci1it2000/formulas) and [Schedula](https://github.com/vinci1it2000/schedula).

I am the project owner of xlcalculator.

xlcalculator uses openpyxl to read Excel files and adds functionality which translates Excel formulas into Python.

An example using xlcalculator with an Excel file:

```
from xlcalculator import ModelCompiler
from xlcalculator import Model
from xlcalculator import Evaluator

filename = r'use_case_01.xlsm'
compiler = ModelCompiler()
new_model = compiler.read_and_parse_archive(filename)
evaluator = Evaluator(new_model)
val1 = evaluator.evaluate('First!A2')
print("value 'evaluated' for First!A2:", val1)
```

An example using xlcalculator with a dict;

```
input_dict = {
    "B4": 0.95,
    "B2": 1000,
    "B19": 0.001,
    "B20": 4,
    # B21
    "B22": 1,
    "B23": 2,
    "B24": 3,
    "B25": "=B2*B4",
    "B26": 5,
    "B27": 6,
    "B28": "=B19*B20*B22",
    "C22": "=SUM(B22:B28)",
  }

from xlcalculator import ModelCompiler
from xlcalculator import Model
from xlcalculator import Evaluator

compiler = ModelCompiler()
my_model = compiler.read_and_parse_dict(input_dict)
evaluator = Evaluator(my_model)

for formula in my_model.formulae:
    print("Formula", formula, "evaluates to", evaluator.evaluate(formula))

# cells need a sheet and Sheet1 is default.
evaluator.set_cell_value("Sheet1!B22", 100)
print("Formula B28 now evaluates to", evaluator.evaluate("Sheet1!B28"))
print("Formula C22 now evaluates to", evaluator.evaluate("Sheet1!C22"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I have solved the matter using a combination of openpyxl and pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook , load_workbook


source_file = "Test.xlsx"
# write to file
wb = load_workbook (source_file)
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "hello world"
ws.append ([10,10])
wb.save(source_file)

# read from file
df = pd.read_excel(source_file)
sum_jan = df ["Jan"].sum() 
print (sum_jan)
```

Answer (score 4):

Openpyxl doesn't support excel 100% for calculating the formula. It supports only very basic formulas. If you want to calculate all formula in workbook you should use [xlwings](http://xlwings.org/) library (which is supported on MacOS and Windows only).