# Extracting the cell.value from Excel workbook using Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to extract the local link from cell using Python. It shows [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is52Y.png) instead of showing the location link.

[Please look at the image here!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is52Y.png)

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: What python package are you using to read the excel sheet? You should post the code you are using so we can help you better.

Comment: I am using openpyxl

Comment: You might need to try to extract the formula and then parse out the link from the formula. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23362361/2280345)

Comment: I looked at it.. I still don't get how to do it? Please help!

Comment: How can I parse out the link from the formula? The link you posted was not about it..

Comment: Have you tried using the data_only=False flag in load_workbook?

Comment: I did. It doesn't work. Still the same..