# Worksheet format breaks when saving excel file with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I try to load excel file for change some values inside it and for read some formulas.
if I get a new excel file (which didn't save with openpyxl), I can read formulas result with code:

```
from openpyxl import *

wb = load_workbook(filename="test1.xlsx",data_only=True)
sheet1 = wb.active
print(sheet1["b9"].value)
### b9 formul is '=SUM(A1+A2+A3)' that's also working in excel.
###output is :37
```

But, If a change something inside file as belown code:

```
from openpyxl import *

wb =load_workbook(filename="test1.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active

sheet["A1"]=42
sheet["A2"]=33
sheet["A3"]=22

wb.save(filename="test1.xlsx")

wb = load_workbook(filename="test1.xlsx",data_only=True)
sheet1 = wb.active
print(sheet1["b9"].value)
##output is : None
```

When I check excel file everythings seems good. formule is right, columns changed, but when I try to read excel formulas with python, I can't see the result, it turns None, if removed data_only=True from workbook also I can see formulas.
What's wrong with my code.

Comment: Are you tried `xlwings` ?

Comment: Did you try to check the content of b9 before you do the edit? Does it contains the equation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Openpyxl 1.8.5: Reading the result of a formula typed in a cell using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350581/openpyxl-1-8-5-reading-the-result-of-a-formula-typed-in-a-cell-using-openpyxl)

Comment: What do you mean "corrupted"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `xlwings`. You can open and see your data like:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book("test1.xlsx")
sht = wb.sheets["Your sheet"]
print(sht.range('B9').value)
```

Or modified it:

```
sht.range('A1').value = 42
sht.range('A2').value = 33
sht.range('A3').value = 22
```

And save it:

```
wb.save()
```

And reopen it:

```
other_wb = xw.Book("test1.xlsx")
sht_other_wb = other_wb["your sheet"]
print(sht_other_wb.range("B9").value)
```

Comment: yes it worked!  
xlwings save commands with microsoft excel, that's so format doesnt break as another libraries.