# Openpyxl get cell value (for cells with formula, no formula, or datetime)

Tags: python, datetime, openpyxl

I have a spreadsheet with cells containing text with no formulas, those with formulas, and those formatted as `datetime`. I need to read the actual value for all these three cases.

Using Python 3 with Openpyxl 3.0.3.

Currently, I have the following code. Using `data_only=True`, as suggested on other SO posts about this kind of problem.

```
workbook = load_workbook(r"path\to\my\spreadsheet.xlsx", data_only=True)
# select first available sheet
sheet = workbook.active
sheet.title

for value in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,
                             max_row=86,
                             min_col=1,
                             max_col=7,
                             values_only=True):
     print(value)
```

A snippet of the resulting output is shown below. In this example, the first column is fine. The third column is date-formatted, but I need the actual value of the cell (so they would be 26/1/2020 and 27/1/2020). The fifth and sixth columns have formulas, but I need the actual value.

```
(2, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 26, 0, 0), None, '=SUM(D$3:D4)', '=E4/E3', None)
(3, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 27, 0, 0), None, '=SUM(D$3:D5)', '=E5/E4', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

*The third column is date-formatted, but I need the actual value of the cell (so they would be 26/1/2020 and 27/1/2020)*
As for formatting there is the `strfomart` 
option from the datetime module in python

```
from datetime import datetime
value[2].strformat("%d/%m/%Y)
```

---

Could you validate that the values are imported and not the formulae in the first place, like it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28100021/7318488)

```
print(sheet["a1"].value)
```

---

**Edit**
I created an Excel Test File with three Columns
[image]

Whats wierd about it is, that it returns the correct output in your for loop.
The output

```
(1, 5, 6)
(2, 7, 9)
(3, 9, 12)
(4, 11, 15)
```

I found the below comment ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23362361/7318488))

> FWIW, as documented in openpyxl.load_workbook(), the value that you
>   get when opening a Workbook with data_only=True is "the value stored
>   the last time Excel read the sheet". This relies on a caching feature
>   of .xls[x/m/...] files (about which I find documentation everywhere
>   except at Microsoft). – user948581

Maybe try to open the file check if the formulas are correctly calculated (displayed as a value in the cell) and then save the file and make sure it is closed.

Comment: And the cells with the formulas? Currently it returns the formula entered, not the resulting value of the cell.

Comment: I tried validating that the values are imported as you suggested, and it gives a syntax error, without explanation.

Comment: could you try in the loop `value.value` ?

Comment: it gives an error: 'tuple' object as no attribute 'value'

Comment: Updated the answer. It's really strange for a mockup example I created it worked totally fine. Btw I just validated I use the same version as you `openpyxl 3.0.3` on `python 3.8`

Comment: I checked the formulas are entered correctly, and the file was saved, and not open when the program is running.

Comment: At this point I am clueless. You could try to create a second test excel file and see if it works there properly

Comment: @AI2110 ***'tuple' object as no attribute 'value'***: Only a `Cell` object has a `value` attribute. You have to remove `values_only=True` and loop the tuple, which is an a sequence of `Cell` objects,