# How to get value from cell which is linked from another sheet, openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

im new with using openpyxl.

I am trying to get value from cell, however value in that cell is linked from another sheet and value what i get is

> `*=<nameOfSheet>t!U2:U1000*`

instead of expected value

> `*1000.2€*`

my approach method  to value is

`ws1.cell(row = i, column = j).value`

thanks for advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reading-the-result-of-a-formula-typed-in-a-cell-using-openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350581)

Comment: @stovfl yes, i am find now answer in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22613272/how-to-access-the-real-value-of-a-cell-using-the-openpyxl-module-for-python)  ... thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

while loading file is needed add to parameter data_only

> `wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)`

This solved my problem.