# openpyxl returns function instead of value evaluation

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am reading from a file like this in `openpyxl`:

```
import openpyxl
from pathlib import WindowsPath

p = WindowsPath(r'.\data\product_version.xlsx')

if p.exists():
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(p)
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows(values_only=True):
        print(row)
```

This should return values only and indeed it does for some columns , while others that are basically excel functions return the function as a value.

```
('WTX84', 'TX', '=MID(A338,1,3)', 'Yes', 'Yes', 258979, 255980)
('WTX90', 'TX', '=MID(A339,1,3)', 'Yes', 'Yes', 258979, 11572174)
```

I want the value `=MID(A338,1,3)` from this.

Comment: You may need to [add an option when loading the workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350581/openpyxl-1-8-5-reading-the-result-of-a-formula-typed-in-a-cell-using-openpyxl)

Comment: maybe you need something like `value = ws['C1']`

Comment: Openpyxl [doesn't evaluate formulas](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/simple_formulae.html?highlight=formula#using-formulae). The reason you see values at all is because Excel, the application, saves the calculated results when saving a file. If you want to evaluate the formulas you need to use another library

Comment: hum ok, so it might be easier to read with pandas

Comment: As Panagiotis Kanavos states Openpyxl doesn't evaluate formulas neither does Pandas. The Openpyxl doc shows as you can either open a workbook to read formulas as the formula or the last calculated value (when it was last opened in Excel and updated) [Loading from a file](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=data_only%3D#loading-from-a-file) If you want to get up to date calulated values you need Xlwings (which uses Excel) or PyCel or Koala.

Comment: @moken but if i open a file with pandas that does the trick . why you saying pandas does not ?